# Matching Regex till a character

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my string:

```
<address>tel+1234567890</address>
```

This is my regex:

```
([\d].*<)
```

which matches this:

> 1234567890<

but I dont want to match the last `<`character.

Comment: Tony the pony, he comes. But seriously, maybe don't use regex to parse XML? You have the `<` inside the parens, so there's no reason it wouldn't be returned as part of the match data. Maybe you just want to grab all characters that aren't a `<`?

Comment: hmm.. Just use `\d+`

Comment: @DaveNewton no its just for practice , i am not parsing

Comment: Why not just

    [\d]

which matches only digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\d+(?=<)
```

The `(?=`...`)` syntax makes sure what's inside the parens matches at that position, without moving the match cursor forward, thus without consuming the input string. It's also called a *zero-width assertion*.

By the way, the square brackets in `[\d]` are redundant, so you can omit them. Also, I've changed the regex, but perhaps you really meant to match this:

```
\d.*?(?=<)
```

This pattern matches everything between a digit and a `<`, including the digit. It makes use of an ungreedy quantifier (`*?`) to match up until the first `<` if there are several.

Answer (score 1):

```
([\d]+)
```

This should work , try it out and let me know

Check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB8tU4/1)

Also as @LucasTrzesniewski said , you can use the look ahead

```
(\d+.(?=<))
```

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jK9iT8/1)